# Проблема с анимацией перехода между фрагментами при инициализации адаптера

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter, recyclerview.adapter, мобильная-разработка

У меня есть два фрагмента при переходе с одного на другой при помощи navigationСontroller используется анимация. И при переходе на второй фрагмент мне нужно проинициализировать recyclerView подготовленными данными. И все работает правильно, но в момент дообавления и обнавления данных в адаптер происходит зависание анимации перехода как можно решить эту проблемку. Можно поставить задержку самый очевидный способ, но может есть какое-то более красивое решение

Comment: Не совсем понял в чем вопрос, но если у вас происходит зависание, то возможно получение самих данных нагружают основной (ui) поток, попробуйте это делать в новом потоке, так же для красоты можно использовать shimmer эффект

Comment: Да вот вопрос в том что если просто получить данные с сервера но не инициализировать адаптер, то все работает плавно

Comment: тогда, могу только предположить что где то в карточке или в onBindViewHolder используются какие то либо задачи нагружающие интерфейс, будь загрузка изображения или еще что. Попробуйте для теста передать в адаптор лишь 1 элемент, если проблема исчезнет - значит дело в отрисовке карточки, если нет значит в методе добавления данных или же их получения. без кода можно лишь предполагать